# Why is this constructor code getting hit?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with some definitions in the constructor:

```
public class Card
{
    public Card()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

}
```

If I call the following:

```
_repository.GetCard(cardId);
```

Where _repository contains this:

```
public Card GetCard(int cardId)
    {
        var card = _db.Cards.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CardId == cardId);  // happens immediately after this is hit
        if (card != null) return card;
        return null;
    }
```

The constructor code is getting hit (I set a breakpoint).  Why is this?  I'm new to C# - I was expecting the constructor to get hit only when objects are created via something like `var newCard = new Card();`.

This is causing problems for me right now because with some objects, I create new objects in the constructor (like history entries to log entity creation) - way too many objects are getting created right now because the constructor code is getting hit so often.

**_db code:**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext, IAppDbContext
{

    public AppDbContext() : base("name=TestConnection")
    {

    }

    public AppDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    void IAppDbContext.Save()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }

    IQueryable<Card> IAppDbContext.Cards
    {
        get { return Cards; }
    }


 }
```

Comment: We need the _db code. It is most likely being newed up there.

Comment: Look at the stacktrace once the breakpoint is hit. *Something* creates the object (EF? LINQ2SQL? Other?) - or the object wouldn't exist :D

Comment: @JustinPihony - just updated my code to include that

Comment: @user2246674 I am using EF, but don't see it creating a new object anywhere... I updated my post to include the _db code if that helps... thanks for the help!

Comment: If you're getting cards back, then they are getting created, which means the constructor got called.  It's your db framework that's creating them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using EntityFramework for retrieving your items from the database. When retrieving them, EF has to create instances of your class to return the data to you. When it creates the instances, it obviously will trigger your constructor. How else could it return instances of your class to you? So somewhere deep inside EF it will call `var entity = new TEntity();`, where TEntity being your Card class.

That's also why EF requires your model objects to have a parameterless constructor.